# Timestamp data stored in UTC, yet the actual timestamp is BST

Tags: google-bigquery, timezone

I'm trying to convert a timestamp column to UTC.

The issue is the column reads it as UTC already, when the timestamps are actually stored in 'Europe/London'.

| current data | expected data |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-26 23:46:18 UTC | 2022-03-26 23:46:18 UTC |
| 2022-03-27 00:15:16 UTC | 2022-03-27 00:15:16 UTC |
| 2022-03-27 02:52:48 UTC | 2022-03-27 01:52:48 UTC |

The 3rd row here looks to be stored in UTC, yet it's actually in BST, so i'm trying to figure out how to convert it to UTC.

The data has been ingested from
Mixpanel, yet a time zone wasn’t applied to the ingestion, hence it has been auto assigned UTC. I was wondering if there’s a way to set this as “Europe/London” within a sql query - without changing any of the numbers for hour in the actual time stamp, so it can be then converted to UTC.

If not current solution is to update past events by selecting the date time ranges of BST over the past 5 years and updating the column, and then try and fix the ingestion for the future.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type: "Note that a TIMESTAMP itself does not have a time zone; it represents the same instant in time globally. However, the display of a timestamp for human readability usually includes a date, a time, and a time zone, in an implementation-dependent format.". If you're seeing data you don't expect, that's likely to be a product of a problem with how the data was inserted - and you haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I’d given enough info originally, I have updated the existing post to reflect more of what has happened. Thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: To be honest, you've lost information from the start - if you had two events an hour apart, but both at 1:30 in the morning on the day of a fall-back (like we'll have on October 30th) it sounds like those have been recorded as the same timestamp. But given that you *have* already converted them to a timestamp, I wouldn't expect there to be any way to view the data as a different type. The approach of "fix up past events and change the ingestion" sounds like the best approach to me. If you can persuade Mixpanel to record the data in UTC to start with, that would be the best option IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the below query to convert BST timestamp data to UTC. Also, BigQuery stores timestamps in UTC.

```
with sample as (
    select timestamp('2022-03-27 02:52:48', 'Europe/London') as ts
)
select timestamp(datetime(ts), 'UTC') as utc_time from sample;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah that’s exactly the issue - because BQ stores time stamps in UTC, and we haven’t specified that the data ingested is “Europe/London”, the data is incorrectly stored in UTC

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps to clarify the concept:

```
select current_timestamp() as current_utc_ts, current_datetime("Europe/London") as current_bst_ts, current_datetime("America/New_York") as current_est_ts
```

[image]